# Where can I find GD compatible fonts?

Tags: php, fonts, gd

I'm using GD to display some text. The default font is Courier (or something similar)... I want to use another font and I found this function: [imageloadfont](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php) that requires a .gdf file. I've search on Google to see if I find some nice fonts, but I didn't find anything. I see there's a script to convert a PNG file to a GDF, but I can't waste too much time so I'd like to know where can I get some nice fonts, or maybe there's another easier way to do what I want.

Comment: Why not use GD`s TrueType capabilities?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hadn't seen the [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) function in the documentation. Thanks [@Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) for the advice. Finally I just copied the consolas.ttf file in the same directory of the script and did:

```
imagettftext ( $image, 12, 0, 200, 100, 0, 'consolas.ttf' , "thanks!");
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This question already has an accepted answer but I am sharing a useful link to get gdf fonts.

http://www.danceswithferrets.org/lab/gdfs/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a converter to convert a truetype font file into gdf?

http://www.lunar.lu/ttf-to-gdf/convert.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to convert 'Consolas' but the result is not good: http://i.imgur.com/BpPWc.png Thanks again!

Comment: ahh I guess it doesn't do anti aliasing well. But I see you've found the solution you were looking for :)

Comment: i think even the link is now broken, i got "404"

Answer (score 0):

Taking the liberty of nicely formatting the code posted by "Cookie" (so I can see it myself ;) :

```
<div style="background:#ffffff;border:5pt solid #000000; color:#000000;padding:25px;border-radius:15px;">
    <div>
        <a href="http://kr1.php.net/imagettftext">http://kr1.php.net/imagettftext</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div>an example...</div>
<?php
    $str = "TESTING...";
    @$i = imagecreate(strlen($str)*20+40,70) or die("FAILED...");
    imagettftext($i,20,30,20,20,imagecolorallocatealpha($i,0,0,0,75),"굴림.ttf",$str)
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    <div style="background:#ffffff;
                border:5pt solid #000000;.
                color:#000000;
                padding:25px;
                border-radius:15px;">
        <div>
            <a href="http://kr1.php.net/imagettftext">
                http://kr1.php.net/imagettftext
            </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            an example...
        </div>

    <?php 
        $str = "TESTING...";
        @$i = imagecreate(strlen($str)*20+40,70) or die("FAILED...");
        magettftext($i,20,30,20,20,imagecolorallocatealpha($i,0,0,0,75),"굴림.ttf",$str);
    ?>
```

sorry... I couldn't test... but maybe It's right.아 참고로 난 중2

Comment: Please format this nicely as no one can understand this. Stack overflow has a nice embedded code feature by indenting each line with 4 spaces.